# Enable/Disable sidebar in Nautilus (aka Files)

Tags: nautilus

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and would like to set the Files (Nautilus) sidebar (where it shows Places, Devices, Network) to default to not being displayed.

It can be toggled on/off with <kbd>F9</kbd>. In preferences you can set hidden files to display or not, but there's no option to set the sidebar to not display by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state start-with-sidebar false
```

It will change default nautilus configuration to doesn't show the sidebar.

If you want to come back to default behavior (nautilus with sidebar) you can  simply set the previous setting to `true`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state start-with-sidebar true
```

---

If you want more information on `gsettings` command you can read the manual:

```
man gsettings
```

I hope this could help you.

Answer (score 9):

### Ubuntu 17.10 and later

Open Files and click the downward point triangle in at the right side of the Files activity in the upper left corner of the desktop to show the Files popup menu. The Files Activity is underlined by an orange line when it is clicked as shown in the below screenshot. Then from the Files menu click *Sidebar*. The Files sidebar is shown when there is a check mark to the left of the Sidebar item in the Files Activity popup menu.

[image]

---

#### Ubuntu 14.04-17.04

1. Open Files and hover the mouse over Files in the upper left corner of the desktop to show the Files menu.
2. Select *View* -> either *Show Sidebar*  or *Sidebar* (depending on the Ubuntu version). The Files sidebar is shown when there is a check mark to the left of the Sidebar item in the Files -> View menu.