# Left side bar with locations like Desktop Documents etc gone in Ubuntu 18.04 Files application

Tags: gnome, files

The files application is not showing Desktop, Documents Music and so on in the left sidebar.

[image: screenshot of files]

What can I do to get it back?

Comment: The same terminal command for Ubuntu 14.04 in [Turn off Files sidebar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766617/turn-off-files-sidebar) also works in 18.04, but Ubuntu 18.04 also has a GUI way to do the same thing that is different from Ubuntu 14.04.