# How do I return to the previous version of nautilus to get back sidebar?

Tags: nautilus

My version of Ubuntu is 18.04.01 LTS download from the official website

How do I get back to the previous versions of Nautilus? is that now it seems different and it does not allow me to access the connected USBs now I only see the normal folders

How I want it to look:

[image]

as it looks now:

[image: as it looks now]

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just uncheck the sidebar? See for example [Enable/Disable sidebar in Nautilus (aka Files)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766617/enable-disable-sidebar-in-nautilus-aka-files)

Comment: thank you very much friend, sincerely do not use Ubuntu one hundred percent why I ask this kind of questions that anyone knows, do not know where to find a guide to learn more, but thank you very much